# Grouping error when changing from sqlite3 to PG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I wrote this in sqlite3:

`@countries = Product.group(:country)`

How can I get the same result with Postgresql?

Comment: what do you mean you want sql query ?

Comment: What is the error? Please update it in your question.

Comment: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-group-by

Answer (score 0):

It will be the same even if the underlying database is Postgres:

```
@countries = Product.group(:country)
```

Because, your active record query using [group](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/group) method generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" GROUP BY country
```

Which is same as [Postgres GROUP BY](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-group-by/).

Answer (score 0):

`group` is an ActiveRecord method it is independent on the database you are using.

To use Postgresql you have to add something like the following to your `config/database.yml`

```
Production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  username: your_username
  password: your_password
  database: your_production_database
  host: your_host
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

And then of course you have to create your database

Answer (score 0):

I thought, you have to find by foreign key of country.

```
@countries = Product.group(:country_id)
```

It will shows countries.